# How can I combine an HTML5 date input type and an HTML5 time input type with jQuery to form a DateTime type?

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint-2010, splistitem

I need to insert a list into a Sharepoint 2010 list from jQuery like so:

```
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
  var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('PostTravelFormFields');

  var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
  this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

  oListItem.set_item('ptli_formFilledOut', new Date());
  oListItem.set_item('ptli_TravelersName ', $('travelername').val());
  oListItem.set_item('ptli_TravelersEmail', $('traveleremail').val());
  oListItem.set_item('ptli_TravelersPhone', $('travelerphone').val());
  oListItem.set_item('ptli_TravelersMailstop', $('travelermailstop').val());
  oListItem.set_item('ptli_TravelersStreetOrPOBox', $('travelerstreetorpobox').val());
  oListItem.set_item('ptli_TravelersDestination', $('travelersdestinations').val());
  oListItem.set_item('ptli_BusinessPurpose', $('ucbusinesspurpose').val());
  oListItem.set_item('ptli_dtDeparture', $('travelersdeparturedate').val());
  oListItem.set_item('ptli_timeDeparture', $('travelersdeparturetime').val());
  . . .
```

But I want to combine values from the HTML5 date input type and the HTML5 time input type:

```
<label class="firstblocklabel">Departure Date:</label>
<input class="dateinput" type="date" id="travelersdeparturedate" required />
<label class="timeLabel">Departure Time:</label>
<input class="timeinput" type="time" id="travelersdeparturetime" />
```

...into one list item (one of datetime data type), not separated out into two, as shown above in the last two lines of jQuery.

Can I do this by concatenating the values (and separated from each other by a space) like so:

```
oListItem.set_item('ptli_dtDeparture', $('travelersdeparturedate').val() + ' ' + $('travelersdeparturetime').val()));
```

? If not, or if this is too kludgy, what is the better way to do it?

Comment: Would the HTML5 input type `datetime-local` do the trick? Looks like it has similar browser support as your current elements.

Comment: Interesting thought; now you've got me thinking about pizza, though...